# For the backlight to work I have to type in sudo modprobe -r apple_gmux everytime

Tags: 12.10, macbook-pro

On my macbook pro the screen brightness key doesn't work.
For it to work I have to type in
`sudo modprobe -r apple_gmux`
`sudo modprobe apple_gmux`
Everytime I start up ubuntu. Is there anyway to fix this or auto run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a script as root on startup, simple edit `/etc/rc.local` file and add the script as separate lines to it, before the `exit 0` line. Remember that you need root privileges to edit that file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and note that `sudo` is not needed when inserting commands in this file, i.e. only add:

```
modprobe -r apple_gmux
modprobe apple_gmux
```